# PHP SOAP Client with Special Characters (Encoding)?

Tags: php, soap, encoding, special-characters, soap-client

I'm trying a SOAP Client with PHP. It is ok as i simply know it. But there is a problem when the `Data contains Special Character` inside.

- Special Character like [♫](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266b/index.htm) inside. (It comes as Hex-code `&#xE;` in the data.)

Following is the sample:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/webservice.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

$result_1 = $client->GetText();
$result_2 = $client->GetText_withSpecialCharacter(); //Data contains `&#xE;` hex-code (♫ Special Character)

var_dump($result_1);
var_dump($result_2);
```

- I **always** got `$result_1` properly
- But, **NEVER** got `$result_2` (It always returns BLANK)

Please suggest me what should i do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the encoding to `UTF-8`

Example

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/webservice.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1, 'encoding'=>' UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $result_1 = urldecode($client->GetText());
 $result_2 = urldecode($client->GetText_withSpecialCharacter());
```

Comment: Still not working. It even returns `NULL` for already working `$result_1`. Whenever i put `urldecode`, `htmlspecialchars_decode`, `htmlentities`, etc to wrap the soap function call there, it always returns `NULL` :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :

```
$myString = $client->GetText_withSpecialCharacter();
$result_2 = urldecode($myString);
if ($myString != urlencode($result_2)) {
  $result_2 = mb_convert_encoding($myString, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($myString,"auto",true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is very old but there is a solution:

```
$result_2 = html_entity_decode($client->GetText_withSpecialCharacter(), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1);
```

But `&#xE;` does not seem to be a valid UTF-8 character. `0xE` is Shift Out character.